# Not able to get the Caldav URL for Zoho calendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, zoho, caldav

How do I get the caldav URL for Zoho calendar which works fine in order to get the events from the calendar. I tried using this URL which doesn't seem to working :

```
https://calendar.zoho.com/caldav/{calendar_id}/events/
```

There is an ical link as well which is working but I want to read the events by using caldav.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing it out. :)